# Zend_Search_Lucen - [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: zend-framework, zend-search-lucene

I´m trying to follow the Zend Lucene Search Tutorial from Ganesh H S and it´s giving me an error.

> Message: fopen(/home/zerego/application/lucene-data/read.lock.file) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied

And if i click in "function.fopen" it show me an other message:

```
Exception

Message: Resource 'function.fopen' not found

Stack trace:

#0 /home/zerego/library/Zend/Acl.php(774): Zend_Acl->get('function.fopen')
#1 /home/zerego/application/plugins/AccessCheck.php(26): Zend_Acl->isAllowed('admin', 'function.fopen', 'index')
```

My folder is with 755 permissions and i have tried with 777 but i thing the problem is with my ACL.

I need to give some kind of permissions in my ACL ? or i need to give those kind of permissions in de .htaccess ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you "click" on the Link shown on your Browser when the error appears or? Your Application trys to open an action "function.fopen" wich is not configured in your acl. But thats not important, the link will send you to php documentation and has nothing to do with your application.

The Error is an permission problem, talk to your webhost if you or the "server" is allowed to write/read from the provided directory (group/user).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.

What worked in my case is that, aside from chmod 777, is that I changed the owner of the files to the web server user.

In my case my web server runs as daemon. Make sure that the web server user is set as the owner of the index directory and the index files within the directory.

You can use the chown command to change the owner of the files and the folder.

you might have to do 'sudo chown daemon'. I had to on my mac because the daemon user isn't an actual user on the mac system.